# Find the probability that an inspector will find more defectives from Worker A than Worker B, and find E(X) and SD

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

**Worker A at Assembly Line I made 15 voltage regulators today and 2 of them are defective. Worker B at Assembly Line II made 20 voltage regulators today and 4 of them are defective. Keep in mind that sampling for quality inspect is without replacement.**

**a) An inspector randomly samples 3 voltage regulars from Worker A's products and 4 voltage regulators from Worker B's products. Find the probability that he will find more defectives from Worker A's products than from Worker B's products.**

**b) All voltage regulators made by Worker A and Worker B are mixed. 8 regulators will be randomly sampled from the entire collection. Among sampled regulators, each regulator made by Worker A receives 4 tokens and each regulator made by Worker B receives 3 tokens. Find the expected value and standard deviations for the total number of tokens.**

What I have tried so far:

a) The way I understand this part is by letting Y = # of defectives from Worker A, and X = # of defectives from Worker B. So it's asking P(Y > X). I started by trying to do this by brute force and just manually computing all possibilities, since the number of possibilities seems small. For example, I started with:

$P(X \le 2 | Y = 3) +  P(X \le 1 | Y = 2) + P(X \le 0 | Y = 1)$

The issue then became how I can actually compute this. I tried using the property

$P(X \le 2 | Y = 3) = \left( \frac{P(X \le 2 \cap Y = 3)}{P(Y=3)} \right)$

Though I still wasn't sure how to compute this. Though once I figured this out, I intended on summing up all of the results to get the overall probability.

b) For the expected value, using the same notation I created in part a, it seemed to be asking for:

$E(4Y + 3X) = 4E(Y) + 3E(X)$

Though at this point I'm getting stuck computing the expected value for this problem. I haven't got to work on standard deviation either, since I am stuck here.